# How can i programatically determine if a Network Adapter is virtual on Windows?

Tags: c++, powershell, winapi, networking, wmi

Using Win32 / IP helper functions, how can I programmatically determine if a Network Adapter is virtual on Windows?

We currently use `GetAdaptersAddresses` to retrieve the addresses associated with the adapters on the local computer. I want to avoid addresses associated with the virtual adapters.

In PowerShell we have below query, which can filter virtual adapters:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where {$_.Virtual –eq $False}
```

How does the above work? If we can get some hints? Then we can also implement the same logic in our C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know a reliable way to identify virtual network adapters.

At least you can do the same as you did with PS and filter the adapters containing 'Virtual' in the description:
Calling `GetAdaptersInfo` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx) you get an array of `PIP_ADAPTER_INFO` structs.
Their `Description` field holds the description you will want to check.